# Add item dynamically in blackberry list field

Tags: listview, blackberry

I am very new to blackberry, i want add item dynamically to list view, i add item statically in list field but i want to some items in dynamically here my code

ListCallBack.java

```
import java.util.Vector;

import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Color;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ListField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ListFieldCallback;

public class ListCallBack implements ListFieldCallback{

private Vector listElements = new Vector();
public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics graphics, int index,
        int y, int width) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String text = (String)listElements.elementAt(index);
    graphics.drawText(text, 0, y, 0, width);
 // Draw a line separator above each field except the first one
    if (index != 0) {
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        graphics.drawLine(0, y, width, y);
    }

}

public Object get(ListField listField, int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listElements.elementAt(index);
}

public int getPreferredWidth(ListField listField) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return Display.getWidth();
}

public int indexOfList(ListField listField, String prefix, int start) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listElements.indexOf(listField);
}

public void insert(String toInsert, int index) {
    listElements.insertElementAt(toInsert, index);
}

public void erase() {
    listElements.removeAllElements();
}
```

}

and ListView.java

```
listItem = new ListField();
listCallBack =new ListCallBack();
listItem.setCallback(listCallBack);

listItem.insert(0);
listCallBack.insert("Can't Text Now Driving", 0);       
listItem.insert(1);
listCallBack.insert("Going to school", 1);    
listItem.insert(2);
listCallBack.insert("Picking Up the Kids", 2);
add(listItem);
```

any one can help me?

Answer (score 2):

you can call invalidate() or invalidate(int index) on ListField object to validate the changes. Just try following

```
// after calling insert(int index) call 
listItem.invalidate(index);

// and after calling erase call 
listItem.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show new items to the List field then add the item  to the vector(in your case add to listElements) then call setsize() method on listfield object with the size of the increased vector.

```
listItem.setSize(listElements.size());
```

you dont directly add items to the listfield. you add it to your collection or array. when ever drawlist will be called for a row it read the data from the collection and render itself.

so simple  do the following steps,

```
listElements.add(Object);

listItem.setSize(listElements.size());
```

you can then call invalidate over itemlist.

I hope i could give you have an idea so that you can find a way...

let me know if you have any doubt.